# Refactor a Ruby switch statement when each case evaluates to the same value?

Tags: ruby

Suppose I have a Ruby switch statement like:

```
x = 1

case name
   when "Bob"
      a = x
   when "Joe"
      b = x
   when "Tom"
      c = x
   ...
end
```

what's the best way to refactor that in a one-liner?

UPDATE: renamed the variables to make it clearer what I'm getting at.

Comment: not very sure what you meant there but you can make a Hash like this `{"Bob" => 1, "Joe" => 1, "Tom" => 1, ..}` and use `hash[key]` to get values

Comment: So depending on a certain value you assign something into different variables? I have a strong feeling that this requires a bit higher-level refactoring that affects the code outside of the given snippet.

Comment: @D-side you might be right, I was just thinking that since in the end whichever variable gets picked it is equal to the same value there was some "ruby magic" way to do it

Comment: Completely agree with @D-Side. This is definitely a case of an [X-Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Solving this as written will leave you with a poor overall solution.

Comment: Don't rush with filling your code with magic, okay? Sure, there are some magicians in the world of Ruby, but [their tricks are often really dangerous](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat). Clear is better tham compact.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, you can use `eval` method, but its not "nice way" to do it.

```
name = "Tom"

a,b,c = [0]*3
config = {"Joe" => "a", "Bob" => "b", "Tom" => "c"}
x = 1

eval("#{config[name]}=#{x}")

puts a, b, c
# => 0
# => 0
# => 1
```

Comment: I made an update where I rename the variables getting set to 1 to make it clearer what im asking.

Comment: @warchildx4 Ok, you can use this, but its not "nice".

Comment: what about if instead of 1 it was a variable that is equal to an integer, so each time the a,b, or c are set to that value, i'm updating my code to show what i mean.

Comment: The part before "But..." addresses a different question, so I would delete it. The part after does address the question. The use of `eval` is one way of doing what the OP wants to do in one line (or maybe three, if you count the creation of the hash and the initialization of the local variables, the latter being necessary, a point you should make). And why not `x = 1; eval("#{config[name]} = #{x.inspect}"); c #=>1` to conform with the question? (`inspect` is needed in case `x` is a string.) Improve you answer and you'll get my upvote.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I remove the "hash" way, bcs you have right, its diferent question. But in your case is not needed the 'inspect' method, bcs x is Fixnum not a string.

Comment: It's a minor point, but adding `inspect` does not limit applicability, but extends it to permit `x` to be a string. My reading of the question is that `x` could be any object, `x=1`being just an example.

Answer (score 1):

I do not advocate the following, but you did ask if your case statement could be restated as a one-liner. This solution requires that `x` be neither `nil` nor `false`:

```
x = 1

name = "Bob"
(name=="Bob" && a=x) || (name=="Velma" && b=x) || (name=="Luigi" && c=x)
a #=> 1
b #=> nil
c #=> nil

name = "Velma"
(name=="Bob" && a=x) || (name=="Velma" && b=x) || (name=="Luigi" && c=x)
a #=> nil
b #=> 1
c #=> nil

name = "Luigi"
(name=="Bob" && a=x) || (name=="Velma" && b=x) || (name=="Luigi" && c=x)
a #=> nil
b #=> nil
c #=> 1

name = "Olivia"
(name=="Bob" && a=x) || (name=="Velma" && b=x) || (name=="Luigi" && c=x)
a #=> nil
b #=> nil
c #=> nil
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use separate variables `a`, `b`, and `c`, I'd create a `results` hash and store the target value in it by `name`:

```
results = {}
results[name] = x
```

and use the corresponding result in my later code.

Comment: problem is a,b,c already exist and continue to exist afterwards

Comment: @warchildx4 You're asking about refactoring, and this is a perfectly valid suggestion. Having several variables like that is downright annoying if this sort of pattern emerges. Match your data structure to fit how you're using it, not the other way around.

Comment: The question is not whether the three given variables should be used. Nor does it ask for a better way to assign values to the variables than the use of the case statement shown.  It merely asks, "what's the best way to refactor that in a one-liner?", which I interpret as the hypothetical quesrtion, "can this be refactored as a one-liner?".  @Lucas is the only one to have addressed that question.

Answer (score 0):

You may have trouble refactoring a case statement into one line, as all the other solutions you've seen thus far are definitely not one lines.

If your true question is just how to refactor that code (as opposed to cramming it into a single line), then instantiating into a Hash like others have pointed out is going to be the way to go. You still need an `if` statement to pull the keys out of that Hash. So perhaps something like:

```
name = "Tom"
people = {"Tom" => 1, "Bob" => 1}
if name == "Tom"
  puts people.fetch("Tom")   # Results in 1
end
```

If everyone's name is going to be equal to `1` though, you could do something nasty like this:

```
if name == "Tom" || name == "Bob" || name == "Harry" then a = 1 end
```

Again, it's a tad unclear what you're looking to do otherwise you might get some better answers from us trying to help. Is there significance to the letter assignment though (eg. `a = 1` is needed vs `b = 1`)? If so, that might change the answer as well.

Please clarify your question if this doesn't help you 100%.

Comment: there is a difference between a and b and each of them are attached to their respective string.

Comment: If you're having to do multiple declarations (eg. a=1, b=1, etc) as well as check for multiple conditions (eg. is `name` Tom? Bob? Etc?), you can start to feel that putting this all in one line is pretty messy. When you think of refactoring, you should be think of clearing/condensing logic and there's not a lot of logic here to condense.